# In ajax-pro Can I use custom class as proxy instead of system.web.ui.page? and How?

Tags: c#, .net, ajaxpro

In ajax-pro Can I use custom class as proxy instead of system.web.ui.page? and How?

basically I want to use html file with ajax-pro

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax-Pro doesn't work this way, it does it's work via a server-side handler and page methods.  Since HTML is static, it can't execute anything on the server, you need some sort of server back-end to support AJAX (unless the rest of the loaded content is also static, in which case you only need a client JavaScript library or hand-roll the JavaScript for AJAX).

If you want static HTML and dynamic AJAX content, I'd look at [jQuery and Web Services to accomplish this](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/), but know that there are **many** solutions out there, not just jQuery.

To answer the question, yes it can, as long as that class inherits from `Page` at some point...but no, you can't use it with a generic HTML file like you describe.